# Using MvvmCross with a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, mvvmcross, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

Is it possible to use a UIPageViewController(iOS) with MvvmCross?

I have used both with Xamarin but I am now trying to use it with MvvmCross.

I basically get to the point where I need to set the UIPageViewControllerDataSource which requires me to override these methods:

```
public override UIViewController GetNextViewController(UIPageViewController pageViewController, UIViewController referenceViewController)
public override UIViewController GetPreviousViewController(UIPageViewController pageViewController, UIViewController referenceViewController)
```

both of which give me a UIViewController back rather than a MvxViewController.

I am very new to MvvmCross and might have missed something but I can see that there are other source classes like MvxSimpleTableViewSource for MvxTableViewController and I would image that there might be a MvxPageViewController with a MvxPageViewControllerDataSource?

Also I see that CheeseBaron has created a binding for the PagerAdapter in android [here](https://github.com/Cheesebaron/Cheesebaron.MvvmCross.Bindings). So Im guessing it is not possible out of the box but I could if I created my own binding like CheeseBaron did?

Am I correct? or is there another way?

Comment: Yes - create copies just as Cheesebaron has. Contribute them back for open source fame and glory!

Answer (score 1):

I took a stab at solving this problem, see [my article here](http://benjaminhysell.com/archive/2014/11/mvvmcross-unified-xamarin-android-viewpager-and-xamarin-ios-uipagecontroluiscrollview-example/), and the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/benhysell/Cheesebaron.MvvmCross.Bindings).

The short version, I didn't use a `UIPageViewController`, but rather did a custom presenter for iOS using a `UIPageControl/UIScrollView` combination.